# Remove WAF policy on Azure Gateway

Tags: azure, azure-networking

On Azure, I need to disassociate an existing WAF policy that is tied to an Azure Application Gateway but cannot find a way.

I've created a new WAF policy and associated it with my Azure Application Gateway. I do not like the way it is configured and would now like to remove it but it gives me an error message saying

> Failed to delete the WAF policy 'wafpolicyNew'. Error: Firewall Policy
> can not be deleted since it is still allocated to resource subscriptions/75d2e0ac-xxxxx450c0a6fc/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/applicationGateways/mygateway

Is there any way I can disassociate the policy from my Application Gateway?

I've tried using Powershell

```
$appGw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -Name "mygateway"
$appGw.FirewallPolicy = $null
Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $appGw
```

But I get another error message saying

> cannot be removed from Application Gateway, changing from one firewall
> policy to another is permitted

and also tried using the Portal to look for a disassociate button but none to be found.

Comment: MS explicitly states that this isn't supported: ["disassociating a policy from the WAF entirely isn't supported"](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/create-waf-policy-ag) (I want this as well)

Comment: Yeah I had to just "live with it". I had to toggle the old rules one by one to match the "defaults". It was a long and painful process that I never want to visit again.

Answer (score 1):

WAF policies can be deleted from an application gateway by using the Azure CLI.

Stop the application gateway.

```
 az network application-gateway stop -g MyResourceGroup -n MyAppGateway
```

Remove the policy

```
 az network application-gateway waf-policy delete --name MyApplicationGatewayWAFPolicy --resource-group MyResourceGroup
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a solution that does not involve stopping the gateway? This is my production environment.

Comment: Did anyone test this? It doesn't work for me. I get "(waf policy) can not be deleted since it is still allocated to resource", even if I stop the associated app gateway.

Answer (score 1):

@Citizen It doesn't work for me. I get "(waf policy) can not be deleted since it is still allocated to resource", even if I stop the associated app gateway.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/ag/create-waf-policy-ag

"Once a Firewall Policy is associated to a WAF, there must always be a policy associated to that WAF. You may overwrite that policy, but disassociating a policy from the WAF entirely isn't supported."

Answer (score 0):

I know this is probably a old thread. But following solution worked for me.

```
 $SubscriptionId = 'xxxx'
 $ResourceGroupName = 'xxxx'
 $GatewayName = 'xxxx'
 Connect-AzAccount -Subscription $SubscriptionId
 $appGw = Get-AzApplicationGateway -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -Name $GatewayName
 $appGw.FirewallPolicy = $null
 $appGw.Sku.Name = 'Standard_v2'
 $appGw.Sku.Tier = 'Standard_v2'
 $appGw.WebApplicationFirewallConfiguration = $null
 $appGW.ForceFirewallPolicyAssociation = $true
 Set-AzApplicationGateway -ApplicationGateway $AppGw
```

You can then make changes to gateway, and the upgrade to the gateway to WAF V2, and associated the WAF policy again.